# placeholder to maintain the height of the space before loading the video iframe

Tags: html, css

I am using iframe for playing video Aparat (a service similar to YouTube). But before the iframe is loaded, the content of the page shakes.

```
<div class="am-sc-video">
  <div id="1654165">
     <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

I Use this css but it had no effect:

```
.am-sc-video::before{
  content: '';
  background: #0B343408;
  padding-bottom: 56.20%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I apologize for my bad English. If it is unclear, please update my question.